# Increase mouse speed

Tags: windows-xp, mouse

Is there any **application** available for Windows XP that allows you to tweak the mouse speed **without needing to restart the OS**. I've recently gotten the Microsoft IntelliMouse Explorere 3.0, but im finding even at the highest mouse speed it is still slow.

Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only real way it seems is if your current mouse cursor is still too slow even at the highest setting is to do the following.

- Increase Hz of the sampling rate of the mouse
- Remove enhance precision

The only real solution to the problem is the DPI of the mouse. If you have a big screen like myself 1920 x 1200 and your mouse DPI is 400 DPI like mine, then its better to go out and buy a gaming mouse that has a higher DPI.

Person flame:
Microsoft Basic Optical Mouse 400 - DPI
Microsoft Intellimouse 3.0 Mouse 400 - DPI

The above just shows the major difference between the IntelliMouse and also their basic Optical mouse that you can pic up for $5 at your local computer store. Not only is the Intellimouse 2x larger and harder to move than the Basic Optical mouse, but it HAS EXACTLY THE SAME DPI!!! So no wonder it feels like pushing a brick.

Recommended Mouse with 2,000 DPI laser is:
[Microsoft Habu Laser Gaming Mouse](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000H16G3W)

Comment: That's my mouse! :)

Comment: Molly can you please give a review of the mouse? I'm going to order it in the next 2-3 days.

Answer (score 2):

**Extra Control Over Mouse Speed**

If you want to tweak the settings for the three mouse-speed settings (MouseSpeed, MouseThreshold1, and MouseThreshold2), launch the registry editor and go to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Mouse\`.

Along with a few other settings, you'll see the three mouse-speed values in the right panel. Mouse-Speed is a multiplier that is set from 0 (always run at the basic speed) to 2 (multiply the calculated speed by 4). MouseThreshold1 indicates the number of pixels you must move the mouse between interrupts to automatically double the basic speed (unless MouseSpeed is not set to 0). By default, MouseThreshold1 ranges from 0 (do not introduce speed-doubling) to 10 pixels, but you can set its value to higher than 10 if you like. Setting the value closer to 1 makes Windows introduce speed-doubling sooner, which causes your pointer to pick up speed.

The last of the three pointer values, MouseThreshold2, behaves like MouseThreshold1 except that it causes Windows to again double the mouse's speed.

*[Source](http://www.activewin.com/tips/reg/mouse_4.shtml)*

Comment: That is helpful but im looking for something that i can test out without having to restart after each and every change.

Comment: @Chad - as you correctly stated in your original question, these changes are probably made at registry level, thus logoff/logon after changing these settings is hardly to be avoided. Tinker with the settings until you're comfy with the speed and leave it at that. or try this switcher: http://download.cnet.com/Mouse-Speed-Switcher/3000-2110_4-10880984.html

Comment: Does killing explorer.exe and then restarting it work instead of a logoff/login or reboot?

Comment: No, you need to log off and back in again. See my answer to my own question.